# Retrieving more error information for Spring JPA Transaction Exception

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions

We are running into some odd behavior and inconsistencies with our transactions when we attempt to save objects and sub-objects. Unfortunately, the error that is being returned to us is not helping us at all. I was wondering if there is a way to obtain more information regarding this exception. We are analyzing our Model classes and JPA annotations to ensure that everything is configured properly. This is currently being run from a jUnit test case. Are there any special considerations that need to be made when saving objects in a transaction? We're not trying to do anything special. We're creating a Parent object along with multiple sub-objects and trying to persist it to the DB. It's just difficult to debug the issue when we're just getting a generic "Could not commit JPA" error. Any help is much appreciated.

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction rolled back because transaction was set to RollbackOnly.
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:476)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:374)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy16.createIncident(Unknown Source)
at eg.test.IncidentTests.testCreateIncident(IncidentTests.java:135)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction rolled back because transaction was set to RollbackOnly.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:63)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
```

Comment: Can you show some code snippets? Maybe part of your bean? DAO? And your unit test. Do you have the right annotations on the unit test?       @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)

Answer (score 1):

You can try enabling sql trace and watch the raw SQL that is executed.

Comment: In my particular case it was also helpful, to check the RDBMS log. The query itself was looking pretty innocent, but the log revealed that it did violated some constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I think you catch and ignore an exception that caused the rollback somewhere. Check the code inside the transaction boundaries for ignored exceptions.

Another possibility is that transaction is explcitly marked as rollback-only by calling `setRollbackOnly()` either on `EntityTransaction` or on `TransactionStatus`.

Comment: I will verify if the transaction is being marked. What's puzzling us is that it will save for basic model updates. It appears that when you start adding sub-objects, that things start to fail. Another thing, no exceptions are occurring within our logic. This is blowing up at the point where spring starts to work its magic. We've enabled SQL logging but that isn't displaying any error information. The last two SQL statement we see right before the exception occurs is when it's getting the next value in the sequence (Running on Oracle DB) for the two objects it's attempting to create.